# Can I get inspired from Patented Algorithm?

Tags: citations, peer-review, legal-issues, patents

I read an algorithm that is patented, I was inspired in one part of it and applied something similar (not exact) to my algorithm (e.g one step they applied out of their 10 steps algorithm I used in my algorithm not exactly identical but similar notion). Will there be any issue?

Can I simply say, this step was inspired from [ ]

Comment: As a side note: AFAIK in Europe algorithms can not be patented, thus patented algorithms from other countries can even commercially be used as far as they are not sold in the said patented countries. Example: Scale Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your question is whether you can cite the patent in a research paper, then yes, absolutely: **patents are fully citable sources**, and patents don't protect publication of related ideas.

If, on the other hand, you want to use your related algorithm commercially, you'd better get legal advice on that...

Comment: The very word "patent" has the archaic meaning of "free to be seen."  The point of the patent system was to enable information about new inventions to be readily available for other people to see, while protecting the original inventor's investment of ideas and effort.  This means the original inventor can make a profit without having to keep the idea a secret, while everyone else can see how the invention works and use that information to make further advances.

Answer (score 10):

If you have a look at

**[Can an algorithm be patented?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/32482/63497)** (Programmers.SX)

You'll notice that:

- In many countries, algorithms, and even software, are simply not patentable.
- Even when software is patentable, it is *not* the case any abstract algorithm is patentable. See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/32518/63497)

So even in a commercial context you might still be safe. Also, person X might be inspired by a patent to publish an academic paper, then person Y could implement the paper by X, and that reduces liability even further if it's legit. I would think.

Comment: Can you clarify "not any abstract algorithm is patentable" - does this mean "no abstract algorithm is patentable"?

Comment: @AlecTeal: Some may be patentable, some are not. I can't clarify because I do not know the details. Luckily where I work it is Not My Job (TM) to worry about whether anything is patentable.

Comment: It seems I am one further, I'm in the EU where it is (as you noted) true that software and algorithms are not patentable. So... there! :P

Comment: Lucky for you, you don't live in the land of the 'free' so you don't have to be one of the brave...

Comment: @AlecTeal Note that in EU software is not patentable but it's protected by *copyright* as works of art. Even if the code you see doesn't have a copyright notice and it's publicly accessible the default is that the author retains all the copyright not that it is in the public domain! Only an explicit open source license can allow you to use the code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have correctly cited the patent, in many countries there is an exemption from patent infringement if the potentially infringing work is academic and/or non-commercial. So, in this case, even if your algorithm does potentially infringe on the patent, you don't need to worry about unless you ever try to commercialise it.

Comment: I think you should s/many/almost all/ actually.